# Store numpy array in session (Alternatives)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, celery, django-sessions

I have a class in a view that does some calculations.

The instance of this class is passed to a Django template context and the results are displayed in the html.

On the other hand, I need to store these results somewhere for later use in another view, where a pdf document is generated using these results.

The results are large lists of data.

For example:

```
def view_one(request):
    # some code
    class_instance = SomeClass(form.cleaned_data)
    html = render_to_string('results.html', {'instance': class_instance})
    return JsonResponse({"result": html})

def view_two(request):
    # some code
    class_pdf = GeneratePdf(class_instance)  # How can I pass the class_instance data?
    # some code
```

The results are large lists of data.

Should I use Django request session to store the data?

Can I use Celery?

There is another alternative?